# Take linear input, convert to geometric sequence and round?

Tags: c, math, 8051, adc

Sorry, struggled a bit thinking up a title.

Basically, I have a piece of code which reads a value from a comparator on my embedded board (8051). This will be a value from 0-255, where 0 is 0V and 255 is 5V.

I need to output these values to a set of eight LEDs, each assigned a bit on variable P1, in human readable fashion (IE like a level meter). Hence, the input value must be rounded so that anything from 16 up to 32 is output as 1, 33 to 48 as 2, 49 to 80 as 4, 81 to 112 as 8 etc.

My only solution that I know will work so far is a string of if-else statements, but I got two layers deep before realising that it's just not going to cut it.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? My brain has turned to mush trying to work out how to do it mathematically.

Thanks!
Joe

EDIT: Here's a snapshot of my calculations, I hope that makes it a bit clearer. http://i.imgur.com/r3n8Ila.png

Comment: I didn't get why you need 42+ to be converted to 2. 
In what order do you want to light LEDs depending on voltage?

Comment: The first LED should be lit up when the voltage passes 6.25% of total, the second at 18.75%, the third at 31.25. I just noticed that I messed up my calculations, so I'll do them again.

To light the LEDs (which are reverse logic), I simply add P1=a;, where a is an 8 bit int. For example, lighting only the msb requires a to equal 0xF7h.

Comment: So, what values you require?
0 -> 0,
33 -> ?,
65 -> ?,
97 -> ?,
...

Comment: Sorry, I work with a wacom pen, here's a screenshot of my calculations http://i.imgur.com/C0H82MO.png

Comment: I suppose it must be 143 on line for 1.5?
/*It's an ADC, not DAC :) */

Comment: Huh yeah, it should. And you're correct, I've been at this for too long.

Comment: It's really a linear relationship : Voltage = BitNumber * 32 - 16 and then you inverse the relation (I'm getting tired too...)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know which bit it will be output to until I know the final result. I get a value in, I have to do some magic to it, and then I get a value that is either 1, 2, 4, 8 etc, depending on whether the number is between 16-32, 33-48 etc.

Comment: BitNumber = round(Voltage/32),  and then of course PortValue = BitNumber << 1 (or stg like that). BUT where does your 32 come from ? did not see it in your charts

Comment: ...I'm not even sure any more.

Comment: If you need the percents you have in your graph, take a look at my answer. Maple calculation shows that values would change on the percents you used in calculation.

Answer (score 1):

I think a math formula that fairly closely fits your data might be

```
BitNumber = floor(voltage / 32 + 1/2)
```

where floor is the nearest integer lower than your result.

This could also be written as

```
BitNumber = round(voltage / 32)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int round8values(int inputVoltage)
{
    return 1 + inputVoltage/32 ;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("31 goes to :  %d \n", round8values(31));
    printf("31 goes to :  %d \n", round8values(42));
    printf("31 goes to :  %d \n", round8values(64));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, for this new list of values, you need floating point arithmetics, like

```
int bitno = (trunc(1 + (val/255.0 - 0.0625)/0.125));
```

Or you can cheat and go to int arithmetics with enough precision:

```
int bitno = ((val*31372 + 515000)/1000000);
```

You will need at least 24bit usigned int for such operation to work without overflow.

Once you have calculated the bit you need, set it:

```
int LEDval = bitno == 0 ? 0 : 1 << (bitno - 1);
```

Or to avoid ternary operation,

```
int LEDval = 0;
if (bitno) LEDval = 1 << (bitno - 1);
```